# American vs British pronunciation of the name "Sanders"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, ipa

Let us assume we have a fellow called "(Name) Sanders". If he were from Britain and I were to choose the Oxford pronunciation rules, how would I write that with IPA?
/ ˈsæn dərs / or / ˈsæn dərz /?

But what if he were American? Which of the two would be the right phonemic/phonetic spelling of his surname?

Comment: "You say tomato. I say tomato." I bought the sheet music and I don't get it. :^)

Comment: I'm no expert on IPA, but I think the main difference would be  in the pronunciation of 'a' rather than the final 's'.

Comment: You ask whether to transcribe the final "s" as /s/ or /z/; obviously /z/, as is usual in BrE, and AmE as far as I know. But the rest of your transcription is un-British; your /æ/ would work only for people who rhyme "demand" with "sand" (as is usual in N. England), and your /ər/ only in rhotic accents (common in Scotland and SW England but rare elsewhere in Britain). For "Oxford", /'sandəz/. /a/ as in "palm".

Comment: @RosieF Could you please post that as an answer, so I can vote for you and mark it closed?  I am fairly sure  /æ/ is American, as is the /ər/ formation.

Comment: There are two names: **Saunders** is one; "Sanders" is another.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, different names, but it's with an "a" as the colonel from KFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask whether to transcribe the final "s" as /s/ or /z/; obviously /z/, as is usual in BrE, and AmE as far as I know. But the rest of your transcription is not British. Your /æ/ would work only for people who rhyme "demand" with "sand" (as is usual in Northern England), and your /ər/ only in rhotic accents (common in Scotland and South-west England but rare elsewhere in Britain).

For how it would be pronounced in an "Oxford" accent (aka BBC or RP, as spoken in some parts of southern England), /'sa:ndəz/. /a:/ is as in "palm".